# Вскрытие линейного конгруэнтного генератора псевдослучайных чисел

Tags: математика, криптография, случайные-числа, взлом, генерация-случайных-данных

В учебных целях, я хочу взломать самый простой ГПCЧ.

Здесь могут помочь даже те, кто не знает про линейный конгруэнтный генератор или про гпсч в принципе, т.к. вопрос в недопонимании английского текста и немного математики.

Для вас вкратце: Есть такая штука как генератор псевдослучайных чисел. т.е. рандом, если проще. "Псевдослучайные" они потому что они не случайны, но похожи на таковые. Одна из реализаций такого генератора:

> X<sub>n+1</sub>=(aX<sub>n</sub>+c) mod m

Где X<sub>n</sub> – это `n`-ый член последовательности. `a`, `c` и `m` – постоянные: `a` – множитель, `c` – инкремент, `m` – модуль. X<sub>0</sub> – начальное значение.

Мои условия взлома:

1. Мы знаем, что генератор основан на линейном конгруэнтном методе.
2. Мы не знаем `a,` `c` и `m`.
3. Мы можем получить любые члены последовательности.

**Задача:** определить `a`,`c`,`m` (с большей вероятностью).

Несколько способов нашел в английском варианте. Мне нужен любой из них или другой, который я не знаю.

На этом [сайте](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24767/crack-linear-congruential-generator-knowing-every-other-word-in-sequence) решают это брутфорсом. Единственное, там дана не вся последовательность, а каждый второй член. Поэтому, насколько я понял, проделывать PowerMod не нужно. Вопросы по этому способу следующие:

1. Я правильно понял, что второй код реализован потому, что первый выдавал два результата, а нам нужен один?
2. Вопрос по модульной арифметике: Как получили, что `c = X2 - ((X1 * a) % m)` (в первом коде)?
3. Почему `m < 10*M_START`?
4. Что происходит во втором коде?

Вот [тут](http://www.itk.ilstu.edu/faculty/chungli/mypapers/CATA2005.pdf) - Plumstead’s algorithm. А [здесь](http://www.reteam.org/papers/e59.pdf) - алгоритм Дж. Марсальи
Поясните пожалуйста, кто понял, с математической точки зрения.

Другие ссылки :

- [Modular arithmetic + division by multiplication + reversible LCG (PRNG) + cracking LCG with Z3](http://yurichev.com/blog/modulo/)
- [Why 1103515245 is used in rand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569113/why-1103515245-is-used-in-rand/8574774#8574774)
- [Cracking a linear congruential generator](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/cracking-a-linear-congruential-generator)
- [Design of Cryptographically Strong Generator By Transforming](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:uKH1I95qNdYJ:seclab1.cs.memphis.edu/files/papers/Mathew-security-paper.pdf)

Comment: Берите и подбирайте, проблем-то? Хоть полным перебором параметров, благо что у вас есть последовательность любой длины.

Answer (score 8):

Окей, смотрите.

1. Здесь авторы решения свели задачу к предыдущей. Действительно, `x[n + 2] = a * x[n + 1] + c = a * (a * x[n] + c) + c = (a * a) * x[n] + (a * c + c)` (mod m), так что задача сводится к взлому линейного конгруэнтного генератора с коэффициентами `a' = a * a` и `c' = a * c + c`. Поэтому мы считаем, что у нас есть *каждый* член *новой* последовательности, и находим новые коэффициенты `a'`, `c'`, а потом вычислим из них старые `a`, `c`.

   Первое решение было квадратично по `а`, `m` (перебор всех `a`/`m` и проверка, что они дают первые несколько членов последовательности правильно), а значит, не сработает на больших модулях, поэтому автор даёт второе решение, которое линейно.
2. Мы считаем, что нам известен каждый член последовательности. Поскольку по условию `x[2] = a' * x[1] + c'` по модулю `m`, то `c' = x[2] - a' * x[1]` по модулю `m`.
3. Константа 10 выглядит случайной. Минимальное возможное значение `m` равно 3159 (т. к. есть член последовательности со значением 3158). Автор решения просто перебирает какое-то количество возможных `m`.
4. Второй код интереснее. Для начала, автор избавляется от `c`, переходя к разностям (для последовательности разностей `y[i] = x[i] - x[i - 1]` имеем `y[i + 1] = a * y[i] (mod m)`). Далее, он пользуется функцией для нахождения *мультипликативного обратного значения* (то есть, для данного `k` это такое `l`, что `k * l = 1 (mod m)`), основываясь на расширенном алгоритме Евклида. Оно существует, [если `k` и `m` взаимно просты](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).

   Итак, `y[2] = a * y[1] (mod m)`, домножив это на обратное `r` к `y[1]`, получаем `a = y[2] * r`. (Если обратное не нашлось, пропускаем это значение `m`.) Если `m` было угадано верно, мы должны получить правильную последовательность разностей, что и проверяется дальнейшим кодом.