# Свой генератор псевдослучайных чисел

Tags: php

Нужно создать свой генератор псевдослучайных чисел на PHP, который при использовании числа (сида), выдаст от 0 до 65280 (включительно) вот такие вот числа подряд:

```
26786
58237
57107
16629
33190
49458
60585
6265
48012
11905
18890
35583
39003
60536
13957
53680
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66623/discussion-on-question-by-user265161----).

Answer (score 1):

Если это какое-то задание скорее всего имеется ввиду линейно-конгруэнтный ГПСЧ.

Его суть довольна проста. Имеется формула

`X(n+1) = (a*X(n)+c) % m`

Ваша задача сводится к нахождению чисел `a` и `c`, `m` у вас будет 65281. 
Подробнее про метод можно посмотреть в [википедии](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4). Также вопрос о "взломе" генераторов такого типа можно посмотреть [тут](https://toster.ru/q/305322). Здесь приводится инструмент для брутфорса таких генераторов

UPD: нашел похожий вопрос на [русском Stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/507106/179990)

Comment: Если рассматривать линейно-конгруэнтный ГПСЧ, то выходит что все X(n) известны, также известно m. В итоге получаются только два неизвестных значения a и c.

Comment: @user265161 Да получается именно так. Только вот проблема в том, что из-за модульных операций все не сводится к простой системе уравнений. Но в ссылке чюна тостер есть упоминание о некоем алгоритме, в который я не в вникал, но который должен вам помочь. Но это все возможно если это именно линейно-конгруэнтный генератор. В противном случае это ничего не решит. Надеюсь помог хоть с направлением в поисках решения вашего вопроса:)

Comment: К сожалению такой способ мне не подходит, уже давно перепробывал ваш метод.