# Написать свой генератор псевдослучайных чисел

Tags: c++, c, математика, случайные-числа, opencl

Необходимо написать свой генератор, т. к. нет возможности добавить библиотеку со встроенным. Можете подсказать пожалуйста ссылку или формулу, по которой можно на C, где будут случайных числа между минимумом и максимумом. Типа `int` и `double`.

P. S. Пишу под OpenCL. Никаких встроенных готовых библиотек с этим нет. Есть варианты, но там сложнее немного. 
Был ли у кого опыт написания примитивного ГПСЧ без каких-либо встроенных функций?

Comment: Вы cstdlib использовать не можете?

Comment: Каким источником энтропии вы планируете воспользоваться? Или Вам таки нужен генератор **псевдослучайных** чисел?

Comment: @vp_arth псевдослучайных, забыл добавить.

Comment: Можно взять алгоритм из [java.util.Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next(int))

Comment: @vp_arth Спасибо, сейчас буду изучать

Comment: @vp_arth хм, там есть псевдослучайные числа, но там не показан метод, для распределения в конкретном диапазоне. Я находил пример, там с битовыми сдвигами, но там опять же псевдослучайное, без границ.

Comment: Там же параметр `bits`: "and returning `(int)(seed >>> (48 - bits))`"

Comment: @vp_arth а, всё, я слепой, спасибо большое, буду тестировать.

Comment: Когда у Вас есть метод возвращающий просто случайный int, привести его к диапазону - элементарно. Что-то вроде `nextRandInt() % (max - min) + min` С double нужно формализовать задачу точнее, что именно означает диапазон)

Comment: @vp_arth а, да, я делал похожее, но выбирал случайные от 0 до 1 и + min. Спасибо

Comment: Связанный вопрос на enSO — [How to get a “random” number in OpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912143/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-opencl).

Answer (score 4):

Для написания своего ГПСЧ можно использовать [линейный конгруэнтный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4). Он довольно часто применяется в реализации стандартной библиотеки. Этот метод может сгенерировать статистически хорошую псевдослучайную последовательность (т. е. часта появления каждого числа будет примерно одинаковой), но этот метод не применим в криптографии, т. к. [может быть легко взломан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507106/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB).

Переносимую реализацию функции `rand` и `srand` можно найти в стандарте языка C (в качестве примера приведена реализация из стандарта C11):

> ```
> static unsigned long long int next = 1;
>
> int rand(void) {
>     next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
>     return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % 32768;
> }
>
> void srand(unsigned int seed) {
>     next = seed;
> }
> ```
>
> ISO/IEC 9899:2011

---

<sub>**Примечания**

*Переменная `next` объявлена статической, т. к. предполагается, что она и (обе функции, к тому же) находится в файле `stdlib.h`.*</sub>

Comment: Мне кажется, тут разумней написать `return (unsigned int)(next>>16)&0x7FFF;`. Явная оптимизация!

Comment: @kisssko, мне кажется, компилятор и сам все сделает. В любом случае, это цитата из стандарта.

Comment: возможно и сделает. Поэтому я и указал - "явная оптимизация". Чтобы не казалось, а точно. :)

Comment: Тогда уж сразу, чего кота за яйца тянуть: `return (unsigned int)next&0x7FFF;`

Answer (score 4):

Когда-то давно (до С++11) писал по второму тому Кнута для 32 и 64 бит - если поможет...

```
class Random
{
public:
    typedef int RandomValue;
    Random& operator = (int seed) { X = seed; return *this; }
    Random(int seed = 1):X(seed){};
    int operator()(int seed = 0)
    {
        const int MM = 2147483647;
        const int AA =      48271;
        const int QQ =      44488;
        const int RR =       3399;
        if (seed != 0) X = seed;
        X = AA*(X%QQ)-RR*(X/QQ);
        if (X < 0) X += MM;
        return X-1;
    }
    int operator()(int min, int max)
    {
        return (*this)()%(max-min) + min;
    }
private:
    int X;
};

class Random64
{
typedef unsigned long long uint64;
public:
    typedef uint64 RandomValue;
    Random64& operator = (uint64 seed) { X = seed; return *this; }
    Random64(uint64 seed = 0):X(seed){};
    uint64 operator()(uint64 seed = uint64(-1))
    {
        const uint64 a = 3202034522624059733ULL;
        const uint64 c =                   1ULL;

        if (seed != uint64(-1)) X = seed;
        uint64 Y = a * X + c;
        X = a * Y + c;
        Y = (Y&0xFFFFFFFF00000000ULL) | (X >> 32);
        return Y;
    }
    uint64 operator()(uint64 min, uint64 max)
    {
        return (*this)()%(max-min) + min;
    }
private:
    uint64 X;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Почему бы вам не использовать стандартный метод для Си:

```
srand(time(NULL));
digit = begin_num + rand() % n;
```

Comment: Я пишу с помощью OpenCL, там встроены самые примитивные вещи. Приходится изворачиваться как могу)

Comment: Не может добавить библиотеку. Автор ответа написал свой генератор в этих условиях: `rand()`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat как я понял из описания, он не может использовать генератор из с++, а не из Си

Comment: @Fresto вообще можно обойтись и без `rand()` - но для этого нужно будет самостоятельно брать время (без time никак не обойтись) и делить его на какое-то большое число. Собственно это то, что делают `srand` и `rand`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, хм, в принципе, время я еще могу передать. А вот со всем остальным вычислением? Есть какое-нибудь примитивный пример для этого? Именно в пределах двух чисел.

Comment: @Fresto как я и писал. Приводите ваше время к int, чтобы можно было разделить и делите на большое число. Таким образом, когда время поменяется, то вы получите другое число. Ну а дальше из полученного число получаете нужное тем же методом, которое я написал в ответь: `begin_num + rand_digit % n`

Comment: rand это не время делённое на большое число, ни в коем случае)

Comment: @vp_arth ну да, я упростил, но для самопального генератора сойдет

Comment: % - очень медленная операция. Я бы брал `rand_digit & (2^n - 1)` и если превышает "границу" делал бы одно вычитание. (где  (2^n - 1) >"границa")

Comment: @Fresto, можно реализовать свои функцию `rand` и `srand`. Существует довольно простой [линейный конгруэнтный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4), реализация есть в стандарте (ну и на вики тоже).

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, вообще можно и без `time`, но нужно будет что-то с seed решить.

Comment: @Fresto Так в OpenCL уже и не Си, а GLSL-подобный язык.

Answer (score 3):

Кому нужно будет, вот решение :

```
main
{
  uint32_t stat[1];
  stat[0] = 2595719;
  uint32_t rang = 0;
  int min = 10;
  int max = 1000;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
      rang = rand(stat) % (max - min) + min;
      cout << "Random Number is " << rang << endl;
  }
}

uint32_t  rand(uint32_t  state[1])
{
  uint32_t x = state[0];
  x ^= x << 13;
  x ^= x >> 17;
  x ^= x << 5;
  state[0] = x;
  return x;
}
```

Предложите, что подкорректировать, если есть варианты

Comment: Оно, вроде как, будет выдавать определенную последовательность чисел каждый запуск программы, разве нет?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, `rand` тоже выдает определенную последовательность чисел каждый запуск программы. Только из-за `srand` она будет каждый раз начинаться с нового числа.

Comment: @eanmos я про это и говорю

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch вот, поэтому в `stat[0]` я добавляю текущее время в секундах, вроде бы должно быть уникальное.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, вы, наверное, не поняли, я про стандартную `rand`.

Comment: @Fresto но ведь там у вас число 2595719

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch а, я после добавил. Это для примера пусть будет. Удивительно даже, никогда не знал, что внутри генератора и как он строится, а всё несложно, оказывается

Comment: @eanmos я про эту функцию: она каждый запуск будет выдовать ровно ту же последовательность, не так ли?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, если сделать `stat[0] = time(NULL)`, то не будет.

Comment: @eanmos в этом случае - да

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить еще один простой пример:

```
class RandInt {
    using Cont = std::valarray<int>;
    Cont v;
    static int k;
public:
    RandInt(int min, int max, size_t seed)
    {
        k = seed;
        int langht = max - min;
        v = Cont(min, langht);
        for (int i = 1; i < langht; ++i)
            v[i] = v[i -1] + 1;

    }
    int operator ()()
    {
        v = v.cshift(k);
        ++k;
        return v[v.size()/2];
    }
};
int RandInt::k;

int main(])
{    
    RandInt r(-25, 25, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        std::cout << r() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Данный пример на C++, можно пожалуйста данную реализацию для Си? Я в вопросе указывал просто это